# Function if checkbox checked and a different function if not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

My mesh will update the position if the radio button with the ID *m1* is checked.

I tried to reach that the mesh is going back to it's original position if "#m1" is not checked any more.

**Do I have to fire a function if checked and a different function if not checked?**

```
<input id="m1" type="radio" name="radio" value="">
<input id="mx" type="radio" name="radio" value="">


var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 0.05, 1 );
var mesh    = new THREE.Mesh( geometry);
mesh.position.set( 0, 0.012, 0 );
mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 2 );
mesh.add( plane );


$('#m1').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
   var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.position).to({ x: 0, y: 0.112, z:0 }, 2000).start();
   tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.In);
   tween.yoyo(true);
 }
});
```

Comment: No, you don't need two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery

```
$('#m1').on("change", function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.position).to({ x: 0, y: 0.112, z:0 }, 2000).start();
        tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.In);
        tween.yoyo(true);
    } else {
        // do another stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use addEventListener(). It is first which came to my mind. Maybe there are better solutions, but I hopu it will be helpfull.

My idea:

```
 myCheckbox.addEventListener("change", check);
 function check(){
     if(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true){
          this code;
     } else {
          this code;
     }
 }
```

You can also include this function in html on checkbox's onChange attribute.